# npm no such file or directory when trying to run 'npm run deploy'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, npm, github-pages

I get this error:

```
no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\nessa\VS Code\React-Django\website\frontend\build'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@1.0.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@1.0.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

when trying to run npm run deploy.

This is my **package.json** file located in my `.\website\frontend`

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.13",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.28.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-speech": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

I've been running npm run dev from the same location all the time without issues. I'm trying to host my react app on Github. I tried reinstalling gh-pages in case a file didn't properly install but am having the same problems. What should I do to resolve this?

**Edit: I tried to do what was said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686358/no-build-folder-found-when-running-npm-run-deploy), but still didn't work. Here's my webpack.config.js if that helps.**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static/frontend'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
    }),
  ],
}
```

I also changed "build": "webpack --mode production" in my package.json scripts to "build": "webpack --mode development", in order to run npm run build, but the problem still isn't fixed.

Comment: Does the "build" folder exist?

Comment: No, is there a way I can install it separately?

Comment: Run `npm run build` (it will create the build folder) and after that `npm run deploy`.

Comment: I edited my original post if that helps, but doing that still didn't do anything. There still doesn't seem to be a build folder.

Comment: In such a case, I would follow some tutorial on webpack to find out why `npm run build` doesn't output a "build" or "dist" folder, or if possible, I would setup a new project using CRA (that will provide everything pre-configured).

Answer (score 9):

In package.json, add:

```json
"scripts": {"predeploy": "npm run build","deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",}
```

**Explanation:**
In my case, I was using Vite to create my React app. So by running `npm run deploy`, vite created a 'dist' folder for the production. But `"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"` is watching for the `build` folder. Now gh-pages will look for `dist` folder before deployment.

Answer (score 1):

This was my error:
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users...\dist'

So I added
`"predeploy": "npm run build",` 
`"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",`
on package.json in `"scripts"`.

And run the command `npm install gh-pages --save-dev` in terminal.

Finishing with `npm run deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

After you add predeploy, deploy in script in JSON file.

1. run : `npm run build`
2. run : `npm run deploy`